why is prefers-color-scheme not working on chromium browser
I have a chrome version
Chrome is up to date
Version 125.0.6422.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and In my global.css i have added the following css property:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  html {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

But whenever I change from the dark mode to light mode it is always red:

As the color scheme has been changed on the browser, but the color is not changed? why it is not working?
I tested this on brave, edge and chrome, same behavior on all.

css-tricks.com : color-scheme is different than prefers-color-scheme
